# Need to automatically Highlight the keywords in the text box using code behind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I m retrieving a text from SQL DB based on the Search criteria i give and displaying in the Textbox in asp.net. I need to highlight the words given in the search criteria in the displayed text.

For example : If i give "need" all the word "need" in textbox that is retrieved and  displayed should be highlight in yellow color. Provide me some code snippets too.

Comment: 9 questions and still no answer accepted? Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

An asp.net `TextBox` renders as either an html `<input type="text">` or a `<textarea>` neither of which support formatting of the text inside.

If you were to display the text in a `Label` or `LiteralControl` it would be easy to just do a `yourString.Replace(searchTerm, "<span style=\"color:yellow\">" + searchTerm + "</span>");` or something similar.

Comment: With some clever css you can potentially make a div look like a textbox, but I agree.....you can't format the text inside an actual textbox.